# Python app thats simulate simple Stock Exchange

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, flask

I wrote this simple app for creating a Stock Exchange platform.
It is written with a flask framework.

My main concerns are regarding the user_page route which feels too long and not DRY enough,
But on the other hand, I can't find a pythonic elegant way to clean it. I would really appreciate your comments.

I am not sure what are the best practices while using flask, Is it best practice to define more functions inside a route?

````
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash
from forms import RegisterPlayers, SalesBids, BuyBids
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'password'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///tmp/test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


# Setting players table
class Users(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    number_of_shares = db.Column(db.Integer())

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Users(user_name: '{self.user_name}', number_of_shares: '{self.number_of_shares}')"


# Setting bids Table
class TradeBids(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    bid_type = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    price_per_share = db.Column(db.Integer())
    share_amount = db.Column(db.Integer())
    trader_name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    bid_status = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"TradeBids(id: '{self.id}', bid type: '{self.bid_type}', price_per_share: '{self.price_per_share}', share_amount: '{self.share_amount}', trader_name: '{self.trader_name}')"


@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    register_form = RegisterPlayers()
    if register_form.validate_on_submit():
        player = Users(user_name=register_form.user_name.data)
        user_name = player.user_name
        all = Users.query.all()
        for name in all:
            if player.user_name in name.user_name:
                return redirect(url_for('user_page', user_name=user_name))
        player.number_of_shares = 0
        db.session.add(player)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('user_page', user_name=user_name))
    return render_template('register.html', form=register_form)


@app.route('/user_page/<user_name>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def user_page(user_name):
    user = Users.query.filter_by(user_name=user_name).first()
    sales_bid_form = SalesBids()
    buy_bids_form = BuyBids()

    if buy_bids_form.validate_on_submit():
        # Save the bid on memory
        bid = TradeBids(bid_type='buy', price_per_share=buy_bids_form.buy_asking_price.data,
                        share_amount=buy_bids_form.buy_shares_amount.data,
                        trader_name=user.user_name,
                        bid_status='pending')

        # handle the bid before it saves to data base
        look_for_match = TradeBids.query.filter(TradeBids.bid_type == 'sell',
                                                TradeBids.price_per_share <= bid.price_per_share,
                                                TradeBids.share_amount >= bid.share_amount,
                                                TradeBids.trader_name != user.user_name,
                                                TradeBids.bid_status == 'pending'
                                                ).order_by(TradeBids.price_per_share).first()

        # we dont have a deal save the bid
        if not look_for_match:
            db.session.add(bid)
            db.session.commit()
            return render_template('user_page.html', user=user, sell_form=sales_bid_form, buy_form=buy_bids_form)

        # we have a deal !!!! exchange shares
        if look_for_match:
            diff = bid.share_amount
            # Update the seller total share
            Users.query.filter_by(user_name=look_for_match.trader_name).update(
                dict(number_of_shares=look_for_match.share_amount - bid.share_amount))
            db.session.commit()

            # Update the buyer total share
            Users.query.filter_by(user_name=user.user_name).update(
                dict(number_of_shares=user.number_of_shares + bid.share_amount))
            db.session.commit()

            # Update the seller bid
            bid_id_to_update = look_for_match.id
            TradeBids.query.filter_by(id=bid_id_to_update).update(
                dict(share_amount=look_for_match.share_amount - bid.share_amount))

            if TradeBids.query.filter_by(id=bid_id_to_update).first().share_amount == 0:
                TradeBids.query.filter_by(id=bid_id_to_update).update(
                    dict(bid_status='expired'))

            db.session.commit()

    if sales_bid_form.validate_on_submit():
        if sales_bid_form.sell_shares_amount.data >= user.number_of_shares:
            flash("insufficient number of shares", 'error')
            return render_template('user_page.html', user=user, sell_form=sales_bid_form, buy_form=buy_bids_form)

        # Save the bid to the memory
        bid = TradeBids(bid_type='sell', price_per_share=sales_bid_form.sell_asking_price.data,
                        share_amount=sales_bid_form.sell_shares_amount.data,
                        trader_name=user.user_name,
                        bid_status='pending')

        # Handle the bid before it saves to Database
        look_for_match = TradeBids.query.filter(TradeBids.bid_type == 'buy',
                                                TradeBids.price_per_share >= bid.price_per_share,
                                                TradeBids.share_amount >= bid.share_amount,
                                                TradeBids.trader_name != user.user_name,
                                                TradeBids.bid_status == 'pending'
                                                ).order_by(TradeBids.price_per_share).first()

        # We dont have a deal save the bid to DB
        if not look_for_match:
            db.session.add(bid)
            db.session.commit()
            return render_template('user_page.html', user=user, sell_form=sales_bid_form, buy_form=buy_bids_form)

        # We have a deal !!!! exchange shares
        if look_for_match:

            # Update the buyer total share
            buyer = Users.query.filter_by(user_name=look_for_match.trader_name).first()
            Users.query.filter_by(user_name=look_for_match.trader_name).update(
                dict(number_of_shares=buyer.number_of_shares + bid.share_amount))
            db.session.commit()

            # Update the seller total share
            Users.query.filter_by(user_name=user.user_name).update(dict(number_of_shares=user.number_of_shares - bid.share_amount))
            db.session.commit()

            # Update the buyer bid
            bid_id_to_update = look_for_match.id
            TradeBids.query.filter_by(id=bid_id_to_update).update(dict(share_amount=look_for_match.share_amount - bid.share_amount))
            if TradeBids.query.filter_by(id=bid_id_to_update).first().share_amount == 0:
                TradeBids.query.filter_by(id=bid_id_to_update).update(
                    dict(bid_status='expired'))

            db.session.commit()

    return render_template('user_page.html', user=user, sell_form=sales_bid_form, buy_form=buy_bids_form)


@app.route('/users_and_bids_tables')
def users_and_bids_tables():
    users = Users.query.all()
    bids = TradeBids.query.all()
    return render_template('all.html', users=users, bids=bids)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to make it more pythonic is to apply the following changes:

1. Factor out models into a separate module; usually we'd call that `models.py`. If there are a lot of models you can split them into submodules under the `models/` package.

   Example:

   - `models\`

     - `user.py`
     - `trade.py`
     - etc.

   Since your app is quite small, `models.py` would be enough.
   Factor out `Users` and `TraderBids` (Usually classes called in the singular) in models.
2. Next, you need to simplify your `user_page()` function.

   I've made an example for you:

   ```py
   # Setting bids Table
   class TradeBids(db.Model):
       id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
       bid_type = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
       price_per_share = db.Column(db.Integer())
       share_amount = db.Column(db.Integer())
       trader_name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
       bid_status = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)

       def __repr__(self):
           return f"TradeBids(id: '{self.id}', " \
                  f"bid type: '{self.bid_type}', " \
                  f"price_per_share: '{self.price_per_share}', " \
                  f"share_amount: '{self.share_amount}', " \
                  f"trader_name: '{self.trader_name}')"

       def try_to_deal(self, user) -> bool:
           # handle the bid before it saves to data base
           look_for_match = TradeBids.query.filter(TradeBids.bid_type == 'sell',
                                                   TradeBids.price_per_share <= self.price_per_share,
                                                   TradeBids.share_amount >= self.share_amount,
                                                   TradeBids.trader_name != user.user_name,
                                                   TradeBids.bid_status == 'pending'
                                                   ).order_by(TradeBids.price_per_share).first()

           # we have a deal !!!! exchange shares
           if look_for_match:
               diff = self.share_amount
               # Update the seller total share
               Users.query.filter_by(user_name=look_for_match.trader_name).update(
                   dict(number_of_shares=look_for_match.share_amount - diff))
               db.session.commit()

               # Update the buyer total share
               Users.query.filter_by(user_name=user.user_name).update(
                   dict(number_of_shares=user.number_of_shares + diff))
               db.session.commit()

               # Update the seller bid
               bid_id_to_update = look_for_match.id
               TradeBids.query.filter_by(id=bid_id_to_update).update(
                   dict(share_amount=look_for_match.share_amount - diff))

               if TradeBids.query.filter_by(id=bid_id_to_update).first().share_amount == 0:
                   TradeBids.query.filter_by(id=bid_id_to_update).update(
                       dict(bid_status='expired'))
               db.session.commit()
           else:
               db.session.add(self)
               db.session.commit()

   ....

   @app.route('/user_page/<user_name>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
   def user_page(user_name):
       user = Users.query.filter_by(user_name=user_name).first()
       sales_bid_form = SalesBids()
       buy_bids_form = BuyBids()

       if buy_bids_form.validate_on_submit():
           # Save the bid on memory
           bid = TradeBids(bid_type='buy', price_per_share=buy_bids_form.buy_asking_price.data,
                           share_amount=buy_bids_form.buy_shares_amount.data,
                           trader_name=user.user_name,
                           bid_status='pending')

           # we dont have a deal save the bid
           if not bid.try_to_deal(user):
               return render_template('user_page.html', user=user, sell_form=sales_bid_form,
                                      buy_form=buy_bids_form)

   ....
   ```

   As you can see I moved part of the logic to the `TradeBids` class. This will improve code readability and maintainability since the logic that belongs to the `TradeBid` is encapsulated in the class. So you can just trigger the needed method in the `user_page` function.
   Move the code into classes, it will make your code more structured.
   I hope you get the point.
3. Use [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) as this will make your life easier.  Even basic stuff will increase code readability and maintainability .

I think that should be enough for the first step.
Good luck.